# Connecting 50ohm coax with regular wires on slipring

Tags: coax

I'm building a device where I need to interface coax cable (50ohm RG174) to a [slipring](https://www.adafruit.com/product/736). The slipring has several channels, breaking out into regular (silver-plated copper) cables. I assume I can simply solder one slipring wire to the coax core and another to the shield. Is there something else I should be on the lookout for?

The coax cable carries a video signal from a [CMOS monochrome image sensor](https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/308/1/NOIP1SN0480A_D-2318156.pdf) which needs to be low-noise.

Comment: That would depend on what signals there are on the coax. Would you please specify that in your post?

Comment: That will give you DC and low frequency continuity. What frequency do you need to go up to? Why is the cable co-ax in the first place?

Comment: How are you going to solder to aluminium, I never could.

Comment: Ahh...wasn't sure about the material for the slipring cables. Just dug for info, and it is silver-plated copper wires, not aluminium. Thanks for the pointer

Comment: Thanks @Justme  - just added more info to the original post

Comment: @Lehman_NG The camera module you linked to has no interface with 50 ohm coax output. Please explain what is transmitted over coaxial cable, analog composite video, digital video like SDI, something else?

Comment: I think asking this question without realizing that it might matter what is in the cable probably means that you aren't going to be able to make this work as well as you want.  Have you considered using wireless to avoid the rotary junction for data?  Just send power through it.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, you can't do what you propose. Your slipring is far too small, and it almost certainly won't support the frequencies you'll need.

You'll have to provide a great deal more information. Specifically, why do you think your coax signals "need to be low-noise"? This suggests that you think you'll be looking at an analog composite video signal, and the chip does not provide that. All inputs and outputs are digital, so "low-noise" isn't a requirement.

What is a requirement is high speed. Your chip requires a 340 MHz LVDS clock, which should be carried on on shielded twisted pair - not coax. Your outputs can be either 3 LVDS pairs or 13 CMOS logic signals. If the former, you need a total of 8 lines on the slipring, and if the latter, 15.

I just don't see how you're going to do this with a 6-wire slipring.

Conceivably, you've got a bunch of extra circuitry which provides something like a video signal and two sync signals (vertical and horizontal). These would be at much lower frequencies than the 680 MHz LVDS, but the video, in particular, would need to be low noise. Perhaps you've generated a composite video signal containing both the video and sync signals, and are looking at more-or-less standard composite video, probably an RS170 signal. I warn you that if you do, you'll lose about 20% of your video field, as RS170 only supports about 480 lines, rather than the 606 of the sensor.

Are you sure you've thought this through?

Comment: Thanks @WhatRoughBeast - my description was a bit overly criptic, yes. I thought the question of connecting coax to non-coax would have a simple answer, but alas ;-)

I'll read up a bit to understand the problem better and then continue the thread - not well thought through yet, indeed...